# How to get all keys with a certain sub value in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the below dictionary

```py
dict = {"A":[1,2,3],"B":[5,6],"C":[3],"D":[3,4,5]}
```

How do I get all the keys that has a 3 in the value list?

So I want to return "A","C","D".

Comment: Please don't ask us to do your homework for you.  What have you tried.

Comment: Start by looping over the dict [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items). Then filter the list of items (using dict comprehension, filter function or just a for loop) by which ones contain `3` (e.g. `if 3 in v` ) . You should not call your dict variable `dict`, as this hides the built in `dict` function.

Answer (score 0):

the expanded answer is:

```
dict = {"A":[1,2,3],"B":[5,6],"C":[3],"D":[3,4,5]}

for i in dict:
    if "3" in str(dict.get(i)):
        print(i)
```

the above code loops over the dictionary and prints out the dictionary keys with values including 3.

Output:

```
A
C
D
```

Rather then printing you could append the keys to a list or create a new dictionary with only the values including 3's. But you should be able to do that.